# Install application and espresso test apk and run on device

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I am very new to android and learning it for the first time.

On my android project, when I do

`gradle build`

`gradle assembleDebugAndroidTest`

I get the application and test apks

So I have these two questions

1) How do I install them on a specific connected device/emulator?

2) How do I start the tests to run on the device ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Where are your tests?

Answer (score 1):

Run `adb devices` to see your connected devices:

```
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
emulator-5556   device
```

Then, use `ANDROID_SERIAL` to specify the one you want.

To install:

```
ANDROID_SERIAL=emulator-5554 gradle installDebug
```

To run tests:

```
ANDROID_SERIAL=emulator-5554 gradle connectedAndroidTestDebug
```

Comment: It doesn't utilize the apk generated using `assembleDebugAndroidTest `.